# Multi-threading method for periodic actions

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, timer, periodic-processing

I have an application that needs to perform a lot of actions, from different modules, periodically once a second. 
The actions are not related to each other.
Some actions are not so much important and can exceed the 1 sec. period by few seconds, but for the other
actions it is very important that they will execute in the 1 sec. period (with up to 400 milliseconds delay).

Until now my development method was to give each action a timer, but now I've reached 40 timers and I notice that
the delay can be long for each action.

My question is this, given the constraints mentioned above, what is the best aproach for my application. 
When to use threads, when to use timers or even tasks?
And maybe I'm even on the wrong framework and .Net can't handle this scenario?!

Thanks for your help,
Hadas

P.S: maybe it is worth mentioning that all the tasks are known from the start, that means my problem is not
dynamically adding tasks, but deciding about developing method for the application.

Comment: about these *important* actions- what is the expected behavior when you have 50 such actions each set to fire every 1 sec? do you expect 50 parallel operations? what if some of then have a run-time greater than 1 sec? do you want a second instance of the same task fire-up when the first instance is yet not finished?

Comment: It sounds like you're building a real-time system. Which means, I think, that you've picked the wrong tool for the job. C# (at least, the standard version from Microsoft with the usual GC) is *not* suitable for building a real-time system.

Comment: @inquisitive, yes some of the actions I would like to start even though their last cycle did not end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you could try:

1) If there are not a huge number of tasks, thread off each one and run a 'while(true){Sleep(requiredIinterval);task()};' loop.  Lower the priority of the threads running the lower-priority tasks so that they get preempted by the higher-priority ones.

Upside: this simple solution is fairly easy to try and may satisfy your requirements.  It is not possible for multiple copies of any task to run.

Downside: The time taken by each task gets added to the const interval, so extending the time between tasks.  Not a good solution for thousands of tasks.

2) Same as above, but get the start time by reading wall-time before the task, get the end time by reading wall-time after the task.  If (requiredIinterval-(end-start)) is positive, convert to ms and Sleep for that interval.

Upside: The time taken for each task does not impact on the timeout unless it is longer than the required interval.  It is not possible for multiple copies of any task to run.

Downside: Not a good solution for thousands of tasks.

3) Implement a delta-ordered priority-queued system.  One way to do this is with a custom threadpool class for each priority and one more 'timerThread' to run a delta-queue of tasks.  The timerThread class holds the deltaQueue - a collection of tasks ordered by timeout-time and an 'inputQueue' for tasks - - a plain concurrentQueue.  The timerThread waits on a semaphore with a timeout set to the timeout-time of the task at the head of the deltaQueue and, if the wait times out, it removes the task, issues it to the threadpool appropriate for its priority and then lops back, gets the timeout-time of the task at the new head of the deltaQueue and waits on the semaphore again.  When any of the threadpools has finished a task, it queues the finished task to the timerThread inputQueue and signals the semaphore. The timerThread then wakes up and, since the wait has returned true, it gets the returned task and re-inserts it into the deltaQueue so that its 'interval is restarted'.

Upside: The time taken for each task does not impact on the timeout unless it is longer than the required interval.  It is not possible for multiple copies of any task to run.  Good solution for many 'timeout tasks'.  The tasks just circulate round the deltaQueue, threadPools and inputQueue, so little GC to screw up the timings.

Downside: Complexity compared to other solutions.  Not sure if the C# threadpool class allows the pooled thread priority to be set - you may have to make your own threadpool class by passing a blockingCollection to a number of explicit thread instances.

4) All other good solutions that I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the comprehensive answer. First thing at work on sunday I will check your suggestions.